# .htaccess RewriteRule not redirecting files, only directories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to get an .htaccess RewriteRule working for the past few days with no success. On the server I am working from, there is a website which allows uploads.  The uploads are stored in folders located in a series of directories such as `/content/uploads/photos/2023/04/<filename>`.  An example filename would be: `upl_35fbde0e97c7be3b8d8c684f538adf0a.jpg`

The content directory is located at the same level of the filesystem as the .htaccess file I am editing.

Instead of serving the file directly, I want to load a PHP file (`files.php?file=<filename>`) which determines if the user is logged in, prior to serving the file.  This should be simple and I was able to get this working easily on another server in a simplified test environment I stood up.

The RewriteRule I created is `RewriteRule ^content/uploads/(.*)$ files.php?file=$1 [L,QSA]`.  I would expect it to redirect the above URL to `/files.php?file=photos/2023/04/upl_35fbde0e97c7be3b8d8c684f538adf0a.jpg`, however no redirect occurs.

If I load the URL `/content/uploads/photos/2023/04/upl_35fbde0e97c7be3b8d8c684f538adf0a.jpg` the file gets served, but not from `files.php` (therefore, unauthenticated users can access).  If I simply chop off the trailing 'g' in the filename so it does not match an existing file, it does load the `files.php` script (EX: `upl_35fbde0e97c7be3b8d8c684f538adf0a.jp`).

I'm a bit at a loss as to why this is happening, as I've tried many different configurations in my .htaccess file, including removing everything else except this redirect rule - but to no avail.  Any suggestions or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I personally redirect all requests through a php router file, using a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/deliver.php$` followed by `RewriteRule (.+) /deliver.php [L,QSA]`. Maybe for your case, something like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/content/uploads/(.*)$` and a `RewriteRule (.+) /files.php`? Then in `files.php`, you'd need to parse the url to get the correct file name, instead of the htaccess doing the pattern matching for you.

Comment: It looks like that should also work, but unfortunately doesn't. It appears something is prioritizing serving the file if found in the path over the htaccess rules - but I can't seem to identify _what_ is doing that.  

Using https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/, both my implementation and yours gets triggered on the URL correctly

Comment: You have referenced both `file.php` and `files.php` in your question - I assume the former is a typo?

Comment: Yes, apologies. The plural is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are perhaps behind a front-end proxy that is serving your static assets (Nginx is often used for this). This is in the interests of "performance". If this is the case then Apache/`.htaccess` is bypassed entirely for static file requests. You would need to configure the proxy to allow these requests through. Check the HTTP response headers (particularly the `Server` header) for clues as to where the response is being served from.

Otherwise, the mod_rewrite rule you've posted would seem to be OK, providing it is placed at the top of the `.htaccess` file and `files.php` is also located at the same level as the `content` subdirectory.

Comment: I've been thinking it may be something to this effect. Looks like Cloudflare may be the culprit here.  I was not sure whether CF would take priority over the redirect, so thanks for confirming.. Let me check with the admin and see.

Comment: @Mad-Chemist All requests go through CF (acting as a proxy), so providing the file has been cached, the file is served directly from CF.

Comment: To close the loop, it was Cloudflare serving the assets directly. Thanks again!